# Get values from a table which are not present only in the 'IN' clause

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, plsql

I want to get values which are not present in the table ,by considering the values only in the IN clause .

For example ,

```
select orderNumber from order where orderNumber in (List of orderNumbers)
```

This will give the orderNumbers which are present in the table by considering the values present in the IN clause , likewise I want the orderNumbers which are not present in the table by considering the values present in the IN clause .

Is there any query logic present to handle this situation?

Comment: do you have another table to bounce the values on? if so, let's say we call it table2, you could use SELECT orderNumber from table2 where orderNumber NOT IN (select orderNumber from table1 where orderNumber IN (list of orderNumbers))... this is assuming you have another table that holds all orderNumbers

Comment: If you're looking for the values which are part of the IN clause plus the values which are not part of the IN clause, there's no need for the IN clause. `SELECT ORDERNUMBER FROM ORDER` ought to do the job. Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a join to do this with a `left outer join` and a `where` clause:

```
select on.*
from (select 1 as OrderNumber from dual union all
      select 2 from dual
      . . .
      select n from dual
     ) ordn left outer join
     orders o
     on o.ordernumber = ordn.ordernumber
where o.ordernumber is NULL;
```

Comment: Wouldn't  the NOT IN operator be a simpler way to extract the desired resultset?

Comment: @PrahaladDeshpande . . . It would be a simpler way to get the wrong results based on what the OP is asking.  The OP is asking for elements of the list (not the table) that are not in the table.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I tried the same query what you have suggested in oracle and DB2 . I am using spring batch which will execute thousands of records. If I use large voluminous records in dual table it is not correctly retrieving records, in oracle .Likewise in DB2 it is showing bad sql grammer error

Comment: @Analysts . . . In db2, you have to use `sysdummy1` instead of `dual`.  In MySQL, you would leave out the `from` clause entirely.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I have done the same as you said by using SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 for db2 and dual for MySQL. For DB2 if the input limit<ordernumber> exceeds 255, db2 is returing SQLCODE=-129 and SQLSTATE = 5404 error, because i am forming the "select 1 from orderNumber from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 unionall" for all 255 inputs at a single strech.so I cant able to use this.  can you help me in this?

Comment: @Analysts . . . the expression should be `select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1 union all select 2 from sysibm.sysdumm1 union all . . .`.

Comment: Hi Gordan, yes of course I did the same query formation based on the input parameter(say n ordernumbers), but DB2 cant able to parse or identify all tables(sysibm.sysdummy1) it seems , so giving SQLCODE=-129 and SQLSTATE=5404 ,error: too many table element

Comment: @Analysts . . . You might be able to use `values()` instead in DB2.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the `MINUS` keyword. This works without an `IN` clause though, but you should be able to make this work for your usecase.

This gives all ordernumbers in `in_clause_table` that are not in `order`.

```
SELECT ordernumbers FROM in_clause_table
MINUS
SELECT orderNumber FROM order;
```

Note: incidentally, there are many ways to achieve this, but I think this might be most concise one.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this without repeating the IN clause would be to use a subquery factoring clause:

```
WITH Q1 AS
  (SELECT ORDERNUMBER
     FROM ORDERS
     WHERE ORDERNUMBER IN (1, 2, 3, 4))
SELECT q.ORDERNUMBER AS INCLUDED_ORDERNUMBER,
       NULL          AS EXCLUDED_ORDERNUMBER
  FROM Q1 q
  UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL          AS INCLUDED_ORDERNUMBER,
         o.ORDERNUMBER AS EXCLUDED_ORDERNUMBER
    FROM ORDERS o
    WHERE o.ORDERNUMBER NOT IN (SELECT ORDERNUMBER FROM Q1);
```

Share and enjoy.